# What might be the benefits in regards to pay-per-click (PPC) for sub-folders vs. microsites

Tags: seo, subdomain, ppc, subdirectory, microsite

I have a client that has a single main site and multiple franchise micro-sites. The micro-sites have most of the functionality that the parent site does but the content is restricted to a specific geographic area:

```
http://mainsite.com
http://mainsite-franchise-a.com
http://mainsite-franchise-b.com
...
```

I want to combine all the micro-sites under the parent domain:

```
http://mainsite.com
http://mainsite.com/franchise-a
http://mainsite.com/franchise-b
...
```

One of the franchises has a very large monthly budget to spend on pay-per-click (PPC) and definitely gets more conversions compared to the referral traffic of the parent site.

What might be the benefits if franchise-a were to let go of his micro-site?

Answer (score 1):

I would use either sub folders or sub-domains for each franchise location. It would let corporate have easier control over the content and less to manage. Plus an easy way to update all franchise sites if needed.

Look at how UPS handles it with each of their stores
http://newyork-ny-1492.theupsstorelocal.com/

It also helps with branding, if people aren't sure what domain to go to, they can always go to the main site and search for their local franchise. This also helps with people traveling who need to find a local franchise location by going to the main site.